# Boolean algebra simplification (x'yz' + x'yz + xyz + x'yz')

Tags: algebra-precalculus, boolean

So I've done a simplification and I'm unsure as to whether or not my process is right. Line 5 feels wrong to me so could someone tell me if this is the correct way to do it?

$$\begin{align}&x’yz' + x'yz + xyz + x'yz'\\
&=yz(x+x') + x'z'(y+y)\\
&=yz + x'yz'\\
&=y(z+x'z')\\
&=y(z+x')(z+z')\\
&=y(z+x')\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Everything ok. The step $z+x'z'=(z+x')(z+z')$ looks strange because it clashes with numerical habits, but it may seem more natural written as follows:
$$A\lor(B\land C)\leftrightarrow(A\lor B)\land(A\lor C)$$
or equivalently (by De Morgan laws)
$$P\land(Q\lor R)\leftrightarrow(P\land Q)\lor(P\land R).$$
These are the distributivity of each of the two laws with respect to the other one. The latter doesn't "clash" when rewritten
$$p\left(q+r\right)=pq+pr.$$